# how to select all files in a directory and run command

Tags: linux, find

I would like to run a command from a tool to merge my files

http://snpeff.sourceforge.net/SnpSift.html#Split

```
java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar split -j file1.vcf file2.vcf file3.vcf ...  > huge.out.vcf
```

I have 400+ files so typing one by one might be erroneous .

I tried something like this

```
 find -name "*.vcf" | java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar split -j > comb.vcf
```

This is the error that I'm getting

```
Error: Cannot 'join' less than two files.
SnpSift split -j
SnpSift version 4.1k (build 2015-09-07), by Pablo Cingolani

Usage: java -jar SnpSift.jar splitChr [-j] [-l <num>] file.vcf [file_2.vcf ... file_N.vcf]
Options:
    -j         : Join all files in command line (output = STDOUT).
    -l <num>   : Split by 'num' lines.
    Default    : Split by chromosome (one file per chromosome).
```

I have used this "find -name" on other tools and it seems to work.

So my question is , how do I select all files in my directory and run command.

Comment: Have no idea of your command but you can give a try to wildcard like this:

`java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar split -j *.vcf > huge.out.vcf`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar split -j file*.vcf
```

Bash will expand file*.vcf to all files in current directory matching file*.vcf.

Pay attention that linux has a maximum size for the length of the command (something like 3MB).

If you want to use find (gives you more fine grain selection), you could use something like this:

```
find . -exec java -jar ~/snpEff_latest_core/snpEff/SnpSift.jar split -j {} \+
```

Here "{}" is replaced by the files found by find and \+ means:

> the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end